Approximating the gradient of $f(x)g(x)$ when $f(x)$ is non-differentiable but has a smooth approximate $h(x)$?
Consider optimizing $\sum_{t=1}^n f_t(x)g_t(x)$ using online gradient descent. However $f_t(x)$ is non-differentiable  and has a smooth approximate $h_t(x)$ . The online gradient descent is as follows:
$$x_{t+1}=x_t-\eta Grad(f_t(x_t)g_t(x_t))$$
I am confused which approximate gradient I should choose:
(1): $\text{Grad}(f_t(x)g_t(x)) \approx h_t^{'}(x)g_t(x)+f_t(x)g_{t}^{'}(x)$
(2): $\text{Grad}(f_t(x)g_t(x)) \approx h_t^{'}(x)g_t(x)+h_t(x)g_{t}^{'}(x)$
Note that
\begin{align}
\left(fg\right)^{\prime}&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)g\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x+h\right)g\left(x\right)+f\left(x+h\right)g\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)}h \\&=f(x)g'(x)+ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} g(x)\\
& \approx f(x)g'(x)+h'(x)g(x),
\end{align}
so I think (1) is more resonable. Am I correct?

Well since $f$ is approximately $h,$ it shouldn't make much difference. I imagine $(1)$ is sometimes better than $(2)$ and vice versa, but this is probably difficult to determine quickly in advance. Just choose one and go with it.

Thank you for your comment. Actually my experiments show (1) is better (in my cases) but I do not know how to persuade others theoretically.

I think it generally depends on the accuracy of the smooth approximation. I don't see any reason to NOT use $f(x)$ since it's exactly what the gradient descent requires (this term doesn't introduce bias to the update). Also, is $f(x)$ nowhere differentiable? Typically, the finite number of non-differentiabilities won't matter for gradient descent since it's rather unlikely it steps right into the non-differentiable point.

$f_t(x)$ is like $f_t(x)=1(x>t)-0.1$, and the smooth function to approximate the indicator is sigmoid function. With fixed step size(I'm dealing with time series so decaying stepsizes are not appropriate), (1) works better than (2).  Do you mean that (1) is exactly what we should use?  I'm not sure if the chain rule is correct in this case.

In (2) there are 2 terms contributing error, while the first only has (1) (and that one term appears in (2)).  In general, the only way (2) would be better than  (1) is if the errors somewhat cancel out, i.e., they are negatively correlated.  In most real-life situations, the error in using h will not be negatively correlated with the error in using h' (one could construct somethng different), so (1) will work better in most real-life cases.
